# How to silently execute exe file without a opening dialogue?

Tags: windows, winrar, exec

I hide two files with rar. An image file and an exe file. When I execute this I get exe file dialogue appearing on the screen. But I don't want to see it. How to do that? 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fewHl.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kdMh.jpg 
This is what i have did But i don't want to see the exe file running.It should run in the background silently.

Comment: No,It didn't answer my question

Comment: If you wish it to start without seeing it, you need to package it as a service that runs when Windows starts, or run it with Task Scheduler on demand.  Ordinary programs will show themselves when run.

Comment: So,are there no other ways that i can work to remove the opening dialogue of exe file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as the after-extraction command

```
start /min "" "mine.exe"
```

Comment: I want to combine exe and image file. When exe file starts executing i don't want to see opening dialogue. So,I cant write the above code in terminal. Check the above video in the question.